# Is this first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation not explicitly or implicitly solvable?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Homework assignment suggests this:

$$(- 3y-3e^x \sin (y)) dx + (-4 x - 6e^x\cos(y) + 4 y) dy = 0$$

To be solvable using the "mixed partials" method for exact differential equations. 
However the test for 'exactness' disagrees with the graded response on the online assignment.

With $M(x,y) = - 3y-3e^x \sin (y)$ and $N(x,y) = -4 x - 6e^x\cos(y) + 4 y$.

$${\partial M\over \partial y}={\partial\over\partial y}(- 3y-3e^x \sin y)= -3-3e^x \cos y$$

and

$${\partial N\over\partial x}={\partial\over\partial x}(-4 x - 6e^x\cos y  + 4 y)= -4 -6e^x\cos y$$

Is there some sort of fault with my partial differentiation, or is the programmed response on the homework in error? Tried finding an integrating factor $\mu(x,y)$ using 
both $(M_y - N_x)\over N$ and $(N_x-M_y)\over M$ but end up being functions of both variables, despite my attempts to simplify them.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please make sure the problem is stated correctly in the first equation? Regards

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the differential equation $$(- 3y-3e^x \sin (y)) dx + (-4 x - 6e^x\cos(y) + 4 y) dy = 0 \tag1$$ is not exact, for the reason you gave: $M_y\ne N_x$.

To make it exact, at least two coefficients would have to be changed: e.g., 
$$(- 3y-3e^x \sin (y)) dx + (-3 x - 3e^x\cos(y) + 4 y) dy = 0 \tag2$$
would be exact.